# How to add leading/trailing spaces to monospace text in Sphinx reStructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Title says it all... this works to create monospace text:

```
``foo``
```

but these do not:

```
`` foo``
``foo ``
```

How can I get leading/trailing spaces in monospace text? (before someone quotes XY problem to me: this is exactly what I want, no more, no less.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grr. This appears to require stupid Sphinx/docutils hackery to workaround, with a custom role.

added to conf.py:

```
import re
from docutils import nodes

tt_re = re.compile('^:tt:`\\|(.*)\\|`$')
def tt_role(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    """
    Can be used as :tt:`|SOME_TEXT_HERE|`,
    where SOME_TEXT_HERE can include leading/trailing spaces
    """
    result = []
    m = tt_re.search(rawtext)
    if m:
        arg = m.group(1)
        result = [nodes.literal('', arg)]
    return result,[]

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('tt', tt_role)
```

Example usage:

```
this :tt:`|  ab12    |` is just like ``foobar`` except it can have leading/trailing spaces.
```

The CSS for `code.literal` should also have a fixed-width font (spaces are kept outside `<span class="pre">` blocks for some reason) and use [`white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Comment: ARGH! This excludes spaces from monospace font. @#%!%#@$%$#@%!

Comment: Grr, it's a CSS thing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work with a ZERO WIDTH SPACE at start in the source

```
Find the file in our Google Drive folder It is located at ``​   foo``
```

where it is ``` ``<zwspace><space><space><space>foo`` ``` in source. Produces html:

```
<code class="docutils literal"><span class="pre">​</span>&#160;&#160; <span class="pre">foo</span></code>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the interpreted text (i.e. within single backquotes), with the first space escaped with the backslash and the literal default role. Consider the following example::

```
.. default-role:: literal

This is the paragraph with inline 
codes: `` foo``, `\  foo` and `\  foo \ `.
```

With sphinx-doc v1.7.4 I get the following html code::

```
<p>This is the paragraph with inline codes: `` foo``, <code class="docutils literal  notranslate"> <span class="pre">foo</span></code> and <code class="docutils literal notranslate"> <span class="pre">foo</span> </code>.</p>
```

The text inside double back quotes is not interpreted [at all](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-literals), while the backslash escaping is done for the content within single backquotes. The `default-role` is needed to change the default role from `title-reference` to the `literal`.

Comment: You don't need to change the default role when specifying the interpreted role like  ```:literal:`\  with spaces \ ` ```